# How can I configure my Nuxt (version 2.13.2) app to use Express?

Tags: express, vue.js, nuxt.js, create-nuxt-app

I have set up several Nuxt applications using ExpressJS on Nuxt version 2.12.x, but the option is no longer present in the configuration setup with `npx create-nuxt-app`.

Previously, `create-nuxt-app` created a file `server/index.js` like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const consola = require('consola')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
const app = express()

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
const config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

async function start() {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server

  await nuxt.ready()
  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  }

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render)

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host)
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  })
}
start()
```

However, using `create-nuxt-app` with Nuxt version 2.13.2 no longer creates this `server/index.js` file. I have tried creating a `server/index.js` file and also `server.js` and neither change the default behavior of the `nuxt` command.

How can I configure my nuxt app to use Express other than downgrading to 2.12?

Comment: You do need change this file, the Nuxt will be installed any thing you needed by Default. On create-nuxt-app  the script asks which modules you would like to be installed. You must select the Express and it will be integrated automatically

Answer (score 1):

Please go through this below link:

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware/

You just need to define the parameter named serverMiddleware in the nuxt.config.js file, and the value of this parameter is the path to your server/index.js file.

Comment: how do you add websocket to this? the serverMiddleware will expose the api endpoint, i need to do http.createServer(app) in order to use websockets